# Product partitions

Tags: combinatorics, data-partitioning

I am looking for information about "Product Partitions" (I don't know the official name)
In the "classic" partition we search the decompositions of a positive integer as sums:

```
Partition(5)   
         5  
       1 4  
       2 3  
     1 1 3  
     1 2 2  
   1 1 1 2  
 1 1 1 1 1
```

I want to find all the decompositions as products:

```
ProductPartition(36)  
      36  
    2 18  
    3 12  
    4 9  
     6 6  
   2 2 9  
   2 3 6  
   3 3 4  
 2 2 3 3
```

I have a recursive solution, but it is not efficient enough.
Thank you very much in advance for any information.

Philippe
PS
Here is my solution (C#):

```
/// <summary>
/// Products Partition 
/// ProductPartition(24) = (24)(2 12)(3 8)(4 6)(2 2 6)(2 3 4)(2 2 2 3)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="N"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private List<List<long>> ProductPartition(long N)
{
    List<List<long>> result = new List<List<long>>();
    if (N == 1)
    {
        return result;
    }
    if (ToolsBox.IsPrime(N))
    {
        result.Add(new List<long>() { N });
        return result;
    }

    long[] D = ToolsBox.Divisors(N); // All divisors of N
    result.Add(new List<long>() { N });
    for (int i = 0; i < D.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        long R = N / D[i];
        foreach (List<long> item in ProductPartition(D[i]))
        {
            List<long> list = new List<long>(item);
            list.Add(R);
            list.Sort();
            result.Add(list);
        }
    }

    // Unfortunatly, there are duplicates
    result = L.Unique(result, Comparer).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

---------------------------------------------- (Jul, 10)
In spite of the various answers posted here, I'm still stuck with performance issues.
If primes is { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29 }, and I apply my version on the product of the first N elements of primes, here the result I get:

```
 N  ProductPartition    ms
 1  Count: 1    CPU:7
 2  Count: 2    CPU:10
 3  Count: 5    CPU:1
 4  Count: 15   CPU:6
 5  Count: 52   CPU:50
 6  Count: 203  CPU:478
 7  Count: 877  CPU:7372
 8  Count: 4140 CPU:56311
 9  Abort after several minutes...
```

I am sure there is better.
Nobody answered me if this function has already been studied and where I could find informations.
I tried several searches on the Internet in vain ...

Thanks again for your help.
Philippe

Comment: What you are wanting to do is called 'Prime Factorization'. The Euclidean Algorithm will be of help. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: I know **prime factorization** and **Euclidean algorithm**, but I don't see how this relates to my question. I am not trying to decompose in prime factors, I want to find all the subsets (not containing 1) whose products are a given integer.

Comment: Why don't you show us the code you have so far, and explain what the problem is?

Comment: Once you have the prime factorization generating these sets is almost trivial (with a caveat about repeating factors)

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#General-purpose

As mentioned in the comments, once you have an algorithm which factors into primes:

```
def allFactors(num):
    primeFactors = algorithm(num)
    return (product(subset) for subset in combinations(primeFactors))
```

[How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/python-code-to-pick-out-all-possible-combinations-from-a-list)